Can isomorphic-style-loader work with react18 renderToPipeableStream?
// server.js
const css = new Set();
const StyleContext = require('isomorphic-style-loader/StyleContext');
const insertCss = (...styles) => styles.forEach(style => css.add(style._getCss()));
const app = <StyleContext.Provider value={{ insertCss }}><Component /></StyleContext.Provider>;
ReactDomServer.renderToPipeableStream(
<html>
  <head>
    <style>{[...css].join('')}</style>
  </head>
  <body><div id="root">{app}</div></body>
</html>, {
 // ...
})

// client.js
const insertCss = (...styles) => {
  const removeCss = styles.map(style => style._insertCss());
  return () => removeCss.forEach(dispose => dispose());
};
const StyleContext = require('isomorphic-style-loader/StyleContext');
const hydratedApp = <StyleContext.Provider value={{ insertCss }}><Component /></StyleContext.Provider>;
hydrateRoot(document.getElementById('root'), hydratedApp);

I tried to update react to 18 in our react ssr framework. But it seems that isomorphic-style-loader does not work with ReactDomServer.renderToPipeableStream?
It can also be seen here in github.

The issue can be solved by react library upgrade guide: link
